# Error generado en Angular al utilizar MatTableModule

Tags: angular, angular-material

esta es mi primer pregunta, así que disculpen si no la realizo bien, estoy tratando de realizar un proyecto en angular, utilizando tablas, justamente con la MatTableModule, pero al importarla me genera un error al ejecutar el ng serve, no logro dar con la solución.

Este es mi archivo app.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule
         
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

este es mi app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyecto028';
}
```

Y este es el error que me genera

```
    ./../../../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\abcd\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2022\common.mjs: Unsupported syntax, expected a string literal.
  6208 |     }
  6209 |     static { this.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "16.1.2", ngImport: i0, type: NgOptimizedImage, deps: [], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Directive }); }
> 6210 |     static { this.ɵdir = i0.ɵɵngDeclareDirective({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "16.1.2", type: NgOptimizedImage, isStandalone: true, selector: "img[ngSrc]", inputs: { ngSrc: "ngSrc", ngSrcset: "ngSrcset", sizes: "sizes", width: ["width", "width", numberAttribute], height: ["height", "height", numberAttribute], loading: "loading", priority: ["priority", "priority", booleanAttribute], loaderParams: "loaderParams", disableOptimizedSrcset: ["disableOptimizedSrcset", "disableOptimizedSrcset", booleanAttribute], fill: ["fill", "fill", booleanAttribute], src: "src", srcset: "srcset" }, host: { properties: { "style.position": "fill ? \"absolute\" : null", "style.width": "fill ? \"100%\" : null", "style.height": "fill ? \"100%\" : null", "style.inset": "fill ? \"0px\" : null" } }, usesOnChanges: true, ngImport: i0 }); }
       |                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                           
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  6211 | }
  6212 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "16.1.2", ngImport: i0, type: NgOptimizedImage, decorators: [{
  6213 |             type: Directive,'



× Failed to compile.
```

Como podran darse cuenta no he ingresado casi nada de codigo, realmente nada, solo la libreria

Estas son las versiones que tengo de angular
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agradezco su ayuda

Agradezco su ayuda, tuve que actualizar mi versión

```
ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] de angular para poder utilizar esa librería

Ya he podido generar una tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta el HTML

Comment: Así es como les comento, no he añadido nada de código, por lo tanto el HTML esta vacío

Comment: ¿Cómo hiciste la configuración del Angular Material?

Comment: Me podrías decir más explícitamente sobre eso, es uno de mis primeros proyectos en angular :/

Comment: Las importaciones parecen correctas, pero que versión de material estas utilizando?

Comment: Por los logs parece que estas usando la versión 16, y no la 15 que corresponde al proyecto que tu tienes instalado. Puede ser ese el problema. Si es así, instala la versión que corresponde a tu angular cli.

Comment: Agregue una nueva imagen de las versiones

Comment: Lo realizare, más tarde agregare que tal

Comment: @Adriana me estas diciendo que el archivo `app.component.html` está vacío?

Comment: Así es, ya lo tenia con codigo pero la librería MatTable no me dejaba avanzar, así que comencé desde cero, pero todo se solucionó actualizando la versión de Angular